# Chronicling America Bulk Downloads

Tags: data-request, media

Any packages written that assist with bulk downloads from [Chronicling America's API](http://chroniclingamerica.loc.gov/about/api/)? I'm interested in both obtaining the OCR text of the newspapers and the newspaper directory.

Answer (score 3):

There is literally a section in the documentation called [Bulk Data](http://chroniclingamerica.loc.gov/about/api/#bulk-data)

> we are beginning to provide bulk access to the underlying data sets

To download all bz2 bulk exports you would only need to loop over the URLs in the JSON

```
{
  "url": "http://chroniclingamerica.loc.gov/data/ocr/batch_mimtptc_beulah_ver01.tar.bz2", 
  "sha1": "ccf9ef6a3d3988d64d226c2839f7df970df7a563", 
  "size": 1706921108, 
  "name": "batch_mimtptc_beulah_ver01.tar.bz2", 
  "created": "2016-03-19T11:25:17-04:00"
}
```

(is an example of one)

Here is a simple python 2.7 code to get the urls

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import requests
import json

url = 'http://chroniclingamerica.loc.gov/ocr.json'

r = requests.get(url)
j = json.loads(r.text)

for t in j.get('ocr'):
    print t.get('url')
```

Although to get all the bz2 files, I'd recommend 'wget' ([example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30612392/2327328))

```
wget -A bz2 -m -p -E -k -K -np http://chroniclingamerica.loc.gov/ocr/
```